# Custom email templates per theme in magento

Tags: zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

Is there a way to customise all the magento transactional emails (font-colours, link colours etc) *per theme* (storefront) without having to create each one though the admin area?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a module that would be able to handle this, though it is not complete (so many templates to edit!).

It involves including a template at the beginning of each email template that includes style information which then gets cascaded down to the rest of the template. If you had multiple themes, you could simply copy the template from /base/default to /your/theme and that should work.

Unfortunately, it has not been an easy module to build. The transactional system in Magento is fairly rigid in what you may do.

Alternatively (and this would be equally as much work) is to have a look at the sales.xml layout. You could rewrite the Email Layouts Section for each theme to point to different templates in your email, but this would be a lot of work and it would still be pretty cumbersome to maintain.